# Index.js:46 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot Read Property 'lifestyle' Of Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jquery,
I am writing an ajax call to retrieve data from an API,

the function is been used on both live and local,

On my local the response comes as

```
var response = res;

var test = response.hearts.assessments.lifestyle
```

on my live, the response comes as

```
var response = res;

var test = response.assessments.lifestyle
```

it comes without [heart]

I need to implement a condition to work with both condition

currently, I have used an if-else condition
but it gives an error of undefined lifestyle on my local.

this is my code

```
var response = res;
            if(typeof(response.assessments.lifestyle) != "undefined" || response.assessments.lifestyle !== null) {
                var lifestyle = response.assessments.lifestyle;               
            }
            else{
                var lifestyle = response.hearts.assessments.lifestyle;
            }
```

But this code won't work,
can someone please help
Thank you..

Comment: Can you provide an example of the content contained in `response`

Comment: yup sure @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Also, having your local environment use different logic than your production environment is a ***really*** bad idea. I'd suggest you solve that problem instead of using JS as a crutch like this.

Comment: You're checking for undefined *after* the undefined, ie you're doing: ok.undefined.ok == undefined - you need to check for ok.undefined - so either `if (typeof(response.hearts) == "undefined")` or `if (typeof(response.assessments) == "undefined")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check that the key "hearts" exists in response.assessments with this method

```
   var response = res;
   if("hearts" in response) {
     var lifestyle = response.hearts.assessments.lifestyle;               
   } else {
     var lifestyle = response.assessments.lifestyle;
   }
```

Comment: tks will check this out

Answer (score 1):

Try as given

```
let response  =  response.assessments || response.hearts.assessments || [];
response = response.lifestyle ||"";
```

if "response.assessments" comes undefined it will check "response.hearts.assessments", If both comes undefined or empty or undefined it will return empty array
second line to check lifestyle property, If it is undefined than blank string